# How to send the http request through interceptors in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Usually we send http request as

```
var req={
}

and add req to the $http.get(req).....
```

But how to sent req from the interceptors ?

Comment: check out this-->   http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/

Answer (score 0):

You want to create interceptor which will build or modify your request.

> The $httpProvider provider contains an array of interceptors. An interceptor is simply a regular service factory that is registered to that array. This is how we create an interceptor:

1. Create one interceptor as factory. Interceptors are the factory methods in Angular it will look like below.

   ```
   var app = angular.module('app', []);
   ```

Here goes your interceptor

```
app.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function() {

  return {
    //Config contains all your request details
    request: function(config) {
       //Do you stuff here. Modify headers,pass params etc

     return config;
    };
 },

 response: function(response) {
      //Do you stuff here with response if any  and return
      return response;
    },
    responseError: function(responseError) {
      //Handle response error here 
    }
  };

});
```

2. Resolve its dependency in $httpProvider. Include this line in you main module file. it may be app.js or nything

   ```
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push( 'myHttpInterceptor');
   ```

Now by this way you can send $http request via interceptors. Hope this helps to you. You can read about interceptors here http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/

Comment: want a interceptor which will build the request

Comment: I gave you same above. Its an interceptor which can build the request. $config has all and you can modify and it before sending request